# What is the relations between $\mathsf{DTIME}(2^{O(n)})$ and $\mathsf{DTIME}(n^{O(\log n)})$

Tags: complexity-theory

What is the relations between $\mathsf{DTIME}(2^{O(n)})$ and $\mathsf{DTIME}(n^{O(\log n)})$? Is one contained in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n = 2^{\log n}$, that means that $n^{\log n} = 2^{(\log n)^2}$. Now you just need to compare $n$ and $(\log n)^2$.

Comment: The other thing is that you need to know the Time Hierarchy Theorem, but I'd guess based on the notation used, that OP knows this.